# Unity Build Showing Black Screen on Startup Using Oculus SDK

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, oculus

Using Windows 10 (x64), Unity 2018.3.4f1, Oculus Standalone Package 1.29.0 & Oculus Integration 1.34.

My app runs well in the editor, but when I try to build and run it, the application shows maybe a split second of the scene and then goes to a black screen. My project had the OpenVR 1.0.2 package, I removed this and was still getting the same issue. Just to test, I started a new project and only imported the Oculus standalone package (without Oculus Integration or openVR), with a simple non-VR camera and the same black screen still occurs.

I had another project with Unity 2018.2.20f1 that was actually crashing. The debugger there brought me to this line on the call stack:

```
[Inline Frame] UnityPlayer.dll!dynamic_array<AllocationRootReference,0>::operator[](unsigned __int64) Line 477    C++
```

The error was a memory access violation.

My project and build settings follow this guide: https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/latest/concepts/unity-build-pc/

Comment: I never used oculus libs. The doc says: 2017.4.17f1 (Recommended) .https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/latest/concepts/unity-req/. Take a look for the right .net version